# Default html page for spring application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a web application with url : localhost:8080/appname/views/welcome.html. So instead of typing the whole url, I want my application to open welcome.html when user types till localhost:8080/appname. So i have done the following changes in my spring config xml.

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

but with this configuration, I am not able to bring my application up in browser instead getting 404 error.

need help on what I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding the following to your web.xml.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/views/welcome.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: @GuruKulki this is how you do on any Java web application, the framework you use (Spring MVC [which **is not** Spring], Play, GWT or another) is not involved in this process. Note that for this approach to work, there should be a real path and file on your application directory that matches with the welcome file description i.e. there must be a *view* folder with a *welcome.html* file inside (this can be an empty file).

Comment: But this way, though the page comes but the dojo components are not getting loaded.

Comment: Well I would guess that the problem is with the paths to your linked resources e.g. Javascript such that they are no resolved properly on path /. Can you post the header of your html with the links. This will probably be the case for the other solution posted as well. In both cases you can force the browser to actually request /views/welcome.html by doing a 302 redirect from / however probanyl easier to fix your paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Spring action and use the value attribute in the @RequestMapping to specify what url to call or invoke that action. When that action is called you return the name of the page which in this case is welcome.html. So you can use this approach to load the welcome.html page by telling to action to map to "/".

```
@Controller
public class CustomController {

@RequestMapping (value = {"/","home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home ()
{
    return "welcome";
}
}
```

so localhost:8080/app-name/
and
   localhost:8080/app-name/home